# Почему я не могу подключиться к БД из другого класса?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, я новичок в Java, прошу вашей помощи!
Есть два класса: один класс основной из которого я пытаюсь подключиться к БД:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DBconnect.main(null);
    //DBconnect.connect() — так тоже писал не робит
```

И собственно второй класс, который это подключение реализовывает:

```
public class DBconnect{

private static final String user = "root";
private static final String password = "0123456789";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    connect();
}

private static void connect(){
    try{
        Driver driver = new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("лог: ок!");
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("лог: ошибко! "+ex);
    }

}
```

Так вот, когда я пытаюсь подключиться к БД из MainActivity я получаю ошибку:

```
лог: ошибко! java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

Но! Когда я запускаю непосредственно сам класс DBconnect, к БД подключаюсь без проблем. Что я делаю не так?
PS код максимально упростил, оставив только суть вопрса

Comment: Потому что `localhost` - это устройство, на котором выполняется код. При запуске "класса" - он выполняется на ПК, а при нормальном запуске выполняется на телефоне/эмуляторе. Нужно чтобы аппарат и сервер с базой были в одной сети и вместо `localhost` указать `ip` устройства с сервером.

Comment: Я даже подумать об этом не мог, спасибо Вам ещё раз. Второй раз помогли!

Comment: Так если помогли - закрой вопрос.